# PowerPoint VSTO (VB.NET) - Inserting a UserControl?

Tags: vba, insert, user-controls, vsto, powerpoint

Like the title says can we insert a UserControl to the PowerPoint slide? Similar to OLE Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, a user control IS an OLE object; you insert them identically.  You just need to know the proper classname.  Hover the mouse over the type of control you want in the Controls section of the Dev tab, remove spaces from whatever the tooltip text tells you and you generally have what you need.  VBA example:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set oSh = .Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, 100, 100, "Forms.CommandButton.1")
    Set oSh = .Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, 100, 100, "Forms.Label.1")
    Set oSh = .Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, 100, 100, "Forms.TextBox.1")
    Set oSh = .Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, 100, 100, "Forms.SpinButton.1")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. This was most helpful. Do you know how to get the class name of the user control?

Comment: As I said, hover your mouse over the type of control .... etc.  No need for me to type it again, is there?  ;-)

Comment: Hello, thanks again. My program is developed in VB.NET VSTO. I did get the class name as "PPTAddinProject.ucPPTAdd". The user control is in VB.NET VSTO. Although the "Forms.CommandButton.1", etc. adds the controls, this UserControl does not.

Comment: I don't use VB.NET so can't help with that.  But are you trying to add a user control to a slide or to a user form?  The code I quoted adds controls to a slide.

Comment: User control to a slide. Is there a way to add the UserForm to the slide?

Comment: No; slides cannot have user forms.  A user form can be part of the VBA project and it *might* be possible to create one via code, but I've never felt the need.